# How to get started with Unreal Engine for iPhone?

Tags: c++, unreal

OK i have decent amount of knowledge of C++. I want to make cool games for iPhone using unreal engine and I have access to UDN. But everything seems cluttered on UDN. I have downloaded source from there. It would be great if someone can provide information about How to get started and list of resources. Thanks!

Comment: This question cannot be reasonably answered because different people approach learning a new topic differently. You're basically asking for a list of links to tutorials, therefore your question should be community wiki.

Comment: Thanks but how to transfer question to community wiki?

Comment: @2600th Don't worry about it, only mods can make questions community wiki nowadays. (I think when regular users _could_ make questions CW, they generally had no idea _when_ to do it anyway)

Comment: Even though it may be right here but down voting(2) a newcomer is not very nice.

Comment: jonathan-hobbs @iamcreasy where exactly bummzack wanted me to post the question and what I've done wrong? Ain't Unreal Engine come under Game Development? Thanks for replies anyway.

Comment: I was under the impression that you can make your question community-wiki by yourself, but apparently I was wrong. Sorry for that. @iamcreasy: I downvoted because this question shows no research effort. From the UDK site it's two clicks (Community > iOS subforum) to get to a lot of resources.

Comment: @bummzack First of all any question can be answered by oneself if he puts enough time/research in it. What if insist of teaching you calculus your teachers would have told you to discover it by self? I posted question here because i thought that there may be people who already are working on it and guide me by telling how they did it. As i mentioned i found the information cluttered on UDN. I wanted to know if someone can suggest some good websites/books/stuff to get started. And if I have source of engine available do I still need to use scripts. Stuff like that I wanted to know. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start of with any tutorials you like(even non-Mobile). First your goal should be getting used to with development environment. If you want to deploy you game to iOS devices then, you just have to follow constrain of that device.

- [Getting Started: iOS Development](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/GettingStartediOSDevelopment.html)
- [UDK Mobile documentation!](http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?t=754537) a forum post you might miss.
- A full game [Jazz Jackrabbit UDK iOS Tutorial](http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?t=754555)
- [Eat3d](http://eat3d.com/training_videos) has some good tutorial on different aspects of Unreal Editor. Like [Kismet](http://eat3d.com/kismet), [Cascade](http://eat3d.com/cascade) etc. Which is not biased towards mobile development, but you need to know them to get a hold onto UDK.
- [3dBuzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com/vbforum/sv_videonav.php?fid=56797c0cd321ddc111e9059535cb3f24) has some tutorials of on Unreal Editor too.